# How do I make a calculation dependent on a certain classification?

Tags: r, criteria

I am trying to make my calculation dependent on which classification I have given my various observations.

An example of my data could look like this:

```
Permno  R&D Industry    Input
1       202    3    
2       414    4    
3       458    5    
4       333    3    
5       294    3    
6       378    5    
7       459    3    
8        69    2    
9       364    1    
10      332    2    
11      112    4    
12      279    1    
13      417    3    
14      454    5    
15      362    5    
16      271    2    
17      252    2    
18      486    5    
19       92    5    
20       99    3
```

In my input variable, I want to e.g. have the following calculations:

```
If Industry = 1 then R&D / 2
If Industry = 2 then R&D / 2
If Industry = 3 then R&D / 6
If Industry = 4 then R&D / 8
If Industry = 5 then R&D / 12
```

How do I incorporate a criteria into my calculation like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `match` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  R.D_new = R.D / c(2, 2, 6, 8, 12)[match(Industry, 1:5)]
)
```

which gives

```
   Permno R.D Industry    R.D_new
1       1 202        3  33.666667
2       2 414        4  51.750000
3       3 458        5  38.166667
4       4 333        3  55.500000
5       5 294        3  49.000000
6       6 378        5  31.500000
7       7 459        3  76.500000
8       8  69        2  34.500000
9       9 364        1 182.000000
10     10 332        2 166.000000
11     11 112        4  14.000000
12     12 279        1 139.500000
13     13 417        3  69.500000
14     14 454        5  37.833333
15     15 362        5  30.166667
16     16 271        2 135.500000
17     17 252        2 126.000000
18     18 486        5  40.500000
19     19  92        5   7.666667
20     20  99        3  16.500000
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Permno = 1:20, R.D = c(202L, 414L, 458L, 333L, 
294L, 378L, 459L, 69L, 364L, 332L, 112L, 279L, 417L, 454L, 362L,
271L, 252L, 486L, 92L, 99L), Industry = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L,
5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA,
-20L))
```

Comment: HA, this is genius!